# Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object

Tags: php, wordpress

The function below is causing a php notice.

[02-Dec-2020 05:04:20 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object in functions.php

```
if ( in_array( 'hndler_nicht-eu', ( array ) $current_user_data->roles ) || in_array( 'hndler_eu_mit_vat', ( array ) $current_user_data->roles ))
    $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
```

I am checking if a user belongs to a certain dealer group and therefore gets tax exempt. I am not sure why this is. Any clues?

Full function:

```
 function wc_diff_rate_for_user( $tax_class, $product ) {
 // Getting the current user 
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
 $current_user_data = get_userdata($current_user->ID);

 if ( in_array( 'hndler_nicht-eu', ( array ) $current_user_data->roles )||   

 in_array( 'hndler_eu_mit_vat', ( array ) $current_user_data->roles ))
     $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

 return $tax_class;
 }
```

---

Update 12/3:

I have changed the function above to the one below. It works fine but its still causing the same PHP notice  :(

```
function my_has_role($user, $role) {
$roles = $user->roles; 
return in_array($role, (array) $user->roles);
}

if (my_has_role($user, 'hndler_nicht-eu') || my_has_role($user,    
'hndler_eu_mit_vat') ) {
// do stuff

$tax_class = 'Zero Rate';
return $tax_class;

}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user',   
10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 
'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That sounds as if $current_user_data is not an object (mayeb it's null or false?). Without more context or a bigger code sample, it's hard to say why.

Comment: Full function added to OP.  Do you by any chance know how to resolve this?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does Ennos assumption apply? Then just check whether `$current_user_data` is an object

Comment: I tried a couple things such as placing (array) in front of 2 variables, thinking its array related. Tried to compare code to previous problems with the same problem. I dont know. My syntax sucks, I am not a coder and this notice seems quite persistent :(

Comment: When you're just starting out, `var_dump` is your best friend. Do a dump (`var_dump($current_user_data)`) and see what it actually is. Your next best friend is [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_userdata/) - always do a search of a built in function you're using so you know what kind of return values it has.

Comment: Oh, hey, WordPress. You could have included that in your tags. get_userdata probably returned FALSE (which happens when it cannot find the user). Are you sure that there's a user logged in? Try checking id is_user_logged_in() might be false.

Comment: I have tried changing ( array ) $current_user_data->roles )  to   $current_user_data->['roles'] thinking that maybe an array is being returned and not an object but this is causing a PHP Fatal error.  How can I see the var_dump output?  I tried it with echo but its not showing anything.

Comment: ...changed the code to the one below. Its still doing the job but debug file is worse.

[code]
function my_has_role($user, $role) {

  $roles = $user->roles; 

  return in_array($role, (array) $user->roles);

}


if (my_has_role($user, 'hndler_nicht-eu') || my_has_role($user, 'hndler_eu_mit_vat') 

) {

  //do stuff
  
   $tax_class = 'Zero Rate';

   return $tax_class;

 
  //
}


 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );

 add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_get_tax_class', 'wc_diff_rate_for_user', 10, 2 );[code]

Comment: First, $current_user_data->['roles'] isn't even correct PHP syntax. If it were an array, you would access it as $current_user_data['roles']. But it most likely is not, the documentation clearly says that get_userdata returns either a WP_User object or FALSE, but no array. So in your case, it probably returned FALSE, and you need to find out why.  How are you running this code? I assume it's on a web server and you're looking at the output via a browser? then try adding the following to your code: `var_dump($current_user_data); var_dump(is_user_logged_in()); die();`, and tell us what you see.